# How do I serve a static page in ASP.NET 5 and redirect users to it?

Tags: c#, asp.net, angularjs

I'm trying to create AngularJS app with the `ASP.NET Web Application` > `empty .net 5` template.
But now I'm trying to build the thing and it's always showing `Hello World`

So I started digging, and found that it was because the `Startup.cs` just returns that;

but now I want to make it so it redirects to the `/wwwroot/index.html`
this is the startup file:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

namespace WebTemplate
{
    public class Startup
    {
        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        // For more information on how to configure your application, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=398940
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
        {
            app.UseIISPlatformHandler();

            app.Run(async (context) =>
            {
                await context.Response.WriteAsync("Hello World!");
            });
        }

        // Entry point for the application.
        public static void Main(string[] args) => WebApplication.Run<Startup>(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: I guess you are missing some steps from here: http://whereslou.com/2014/05/28/asp-net-moving-parts-ibuilder/.

Answer (score 0):

With this Configure implementation you will serve index.html statically:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
{        
   app.UseStaticFiles();
   app.UseDefaultFiles(new Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles.DefaultFilesOptions() { DefaultFileNames = new[] { "index.html" } });          
}
```

The documentation for this is [here](http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/static-files.html). The DefaultFilesOptions is actually also not needed since index.html is in the default list anyway.

Sorry for my last post... that was really a bad solution.

Comment: I don't know if it is because I did something wrong, but with that I only get: `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)`

Comment: Is "webroot": "wwwroot", added to project.json? ...and is index.html in the root of the wwwroot folder?

Comment: I added UseStaticFiles before UseDefaultFiles. According to the documentation you need this.. maybe this is the missing point (although it works for me without it.). If it's still not working could you paste your project.json file into the question? (And btw, sometimes just removing the artifacts folder also helps...)